# ionic v1 build windows 10 ou 8.1

Tags: ionic, build

Estou tentando fazer a build de um app teste para windows 10 ou 8.1.
Já adicionei no `config.xml`: `<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />`

Ai no console executo os seguintes comandos:

1 - `ionic cordova platform add windows`
2 - `ionic cordova build windows`

E me apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build windows (exit code 1):


        You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
        Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\max-desktop\Desktop\easyjob\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\max-desktop\Desktop\easyjob
        add to body class: platform-windows
        MSBuild v4.0 is not supported, aborting.
        Error: AppPackages doesn't exists
```

Já pesquisei bastante mas não sei o que fazer...

**OBS: Estou utilizando o ionic v1**

> Atualização da pergunta

Como o comentário do Otto sugere, instalei em minha máquina o `windows sdk 10`, porém ao rodar a build o console ainda me apresenta o mesmo erro:

```
[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build windows (exit code 1):


        You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
        Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\max-desktop\Desktop\easyjob\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\max-desktop\Desktop\easyjob
        add to body class: platform-windows
        MSBuild v4.0 is not supported, aborting.
        Error: AppPackages doesn't exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa instalar o Windows 10 SDK ou 8.1 para resolver o problema.

Precisaria instalar separadamente do VS 2015 e adicionar a linha abaixo ao **config.xml**:

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

Aproveita também e da uma olhada nesse link, tem uma resposta mais completa, caso lhe ajude complemento aqui com a resposta completa.

https://blog.aveni.us/index.php/2015/12/19/creating-windows-10-universal-apps-ionic-framework/#sthash.8YtHmFrE.dpbs

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: @MaxRogério atualizei com um link complementar da uma olhada.

Comment: Cara, não sei mas não estou conseguindo... :/